# Smallest value of $a^2 + b^2 + c^2+ d^2$, given values for $(a+b)(c+d)$, $(a+c)(b+d)$, and $(a+d)(b+c)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$, and
>   $$(a+b)(c+d)=143 \qquad (a+c)(b+d)=150 \qquad (a+d)(b+c)=169$$
>   Find the smallest possible value of 
>   $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2+ d^2$$

I thought of adding $7$ to the first equation and make it equal the second, solving, and finding a new equation.

Do it $3$ times, keep substituting, but this is a very very very long approach *if it's even an approach*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lambda = a + b + c + d$. When you sum over the 3 equations.

$$(a+b)(c+d)=143,\quad (a+c)(b+d)=150,\quad (a+d)(b+c)=169\tag{*1}$$

LHS sums to
$$2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd) = (a+b+c+d)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$$
while RHS sums to $462$. This leads to
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = \lambda^2 - 462$$
To minimize $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, one just need to minimize $\lambda^2$. If you look at LHS
of the 3 equations, all of them is a product of $2$ factors which sum to $\lambda$.
In general, if we have $p + q = \lambda$, then
$$4pq = (p+q)^2 - (p-q)^2 \le (p+q)^2 = \lambda^2$$
The set of 3 equations tell us

$$\begin{align}\lambda^2 &\ge 4\max\{ (a+b)(c+d), (a+c)(b+d), (a+d)(b+c) \}\\
&= 4\max\{ 143, 150, 169 \}\\&= 676\end{align}$$

As a result, 
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = \lambda^2 - 462 \ge 214$$

To see $214$ is the actual minimum, we need to find $(a,b,c,d)$ which satisfies $(*1)$ and $\lambda^2 = 676 = 26^2$.

Flipping all the signs of $a,b,c,d$ if necessary, we can assume $\lambda = 26$.

The third equation $(a+d)(b+c) = 169 = 13^2 = \frac14 (26)^2$ tell us
$a + d = b + c$.
Introduce $u,v$ such that

$$(a,b,c,d) = \left( \frac{13+u}{2}, \frac{13+v}{2}, \frac{13-v}{2}, \frac{13-u}{2}\right)$$

and substitute into the first and second equation and simplify, we obtain

$$\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right)^2 = 26\quad\text{ and }\quad \left(\frac{u-v}{2}\right)^2 = 19$$

Using this, we find following 4-tuple

$$(a,b,c,d) = {\small \left(
\frac{13+\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}}{2},
\frac{13+\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}}{2},
\frac{13-\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}}{2},
\frac{13-\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}}{2}
\right)}$$
is a solution of the 3 equations in $(*1)$ with $a + b + c + d = 26$. 
One can verify $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 214$ for this particular solution. As a result, the lower bound $214$ is achievable and $214$ is the smallest possible value we seek.

Comment: why that line of 4pq = (p+q)^2 ....

Comment: substitute $(p,q)$ by $(a+b,c+d), (a+c,b+d), (a+d,b+c)$, you get 3 inequalities which can be combined to get the next $\lambda^2 \ge \max(\cdots)$ inequality.

Comment: Forgive me, how did you get the inequality? maybe it's name and I'll search for it or smth

Comment: There is no name, this is basic property of $\max$. $$A \ge B_1 \text{ and } A \ge B_2 \text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } A \ge B_m \iff A \ge \max(B_1,B_2,\cdots,B_m)$$

Comment: well, I'm sorry but i still didn't understand that 4pq line ~_~ I don't feel like I'm an engineering student after I saw this

Answer (score 1):

Using A.M.-G.M. we get: $$169+143+150=(a+b)(c+d)+(a+c)(b+d)+(a+d)(b+c)=$$

$$2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2ab+2cd \leq 3a^2+3b^2+3c^2+3d^2$$

So $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\geq 154$$

But, unfortenuly this is not the minumum, since variables can not be all the same.

Comment: Cant understand why there's an inquality there

Comment: $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$........

Comment: 2xy <= x^2 + y^^2 ? not xy <= y^2 + x^2 ?

Comment: First.............

Comment: I don't know how your answer addresses the question. You just show a lower bound, not the minimum.