# Minimizing $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ for positive reals satisfying $(a+b) (c+d)=143$, $(a+c)(b+d)=150$, $(a+d) (b+c)=169$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone do this?

> Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are positive real numbers that satisfy the system of equations
> $$\begin{align}
> (a+b) (c+d)&=143 \\
> (a+c) (b+d)&=150 \\
> (a+d) (b+c)&=169
> \end{align}$$
> Compute the smallest possible value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Comment: Show your work and use MathJax

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014786/smallest-value-of-a2-b2-c2-d2-given-values-for-abcd-ac?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

From math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014786/…  we get  $a+d=b+c$.

System
$$\begin{align}
(a+b) (c+d)&=143 \\
(a+c) (b+d)&=150 \\
(a+d) (b+c)&=169\\
a+d=b+c
\end{align}$$
has 8 solutions

$a=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}$;

$a=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}$;

$a=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}$;

$a=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}$;

$a=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}$;

$a=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}$;

$a=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}$;

$a=\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}b=\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}-13}{2}\operatorname{,}c=-\frac{\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{19}+13}{2}\operatorname{,}d=-\frac{\sqrt{26}+\sqrt{19}+13}{2}$.

On all solutions function $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ has minimal value 214.

First 4 solutions is positive.