# Maximizing $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ with given constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, systems-of-equations

The following problem is from a local contest which ended today:

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers such that $$(a+b)(c+d)=143\\ (a+c)(b+d)=150\\ (a+d)(b+c)=169$$ Find the maximum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$.

Here are my workings:

We have $$\tag{1}ac+bc+bd+ad=143$$ $$\tag{2}{ab+bc+cd+ad=150}$$ $$\tag{3}{ab+bd+ac+cd=169}$$
Summing $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have $$2(ab+bc+cd+ac+ad+bd)=462$$
We have $$\begin{align} a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 &=(a+b+c+d)^2-2(ab+bc+cd+ac+ad+bd)\\ &= (a+b+c+d)^2-462\end{align}$$
So we have to maximize $a+b+c+d$.

I can't proceed from here. Minimizing the expression seems easy by Cauchy-Schwarz or AM-GM but I don't know how to maximize this.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3014786/947379) (about minimizing)(not a duplicate)

Comment: There is no maximum. You can show that for $ a+b+c + d = E \geq 26$, we can always find solutions to the above. EG Set $c+d$ to be (one of) the roots to $x(E-x) -143 = 0 $, etc and solve the simultaneous linear equations. (We have 4 equations with non-zero determinant, hence have a unique solution, up to choosing the root)  $\quad$ Did you perchance remember the question wrongly?

Comment: @CalvinLin I checked. The question asks for the maximum but there is an issue that $a,b,c,d$ are all positive.

Comment: What happens if you put a "boundary value" of zero for one of the variables?

Comment: A simple logic can work out to figure if the system has maximum or not.Let a,b,c be infinitely small.So d alone contributes to the answer. Now (a+b+c+d)^2-d^2 =462.

Comment: @mechanics Are you sure the conditions in the question can still be satisfied with these (seemingly random) selections? EG We will likely need $a \neq b \neq c$.

Comment: @calvin lin,by infintiely small,I don't mean all the three to be same.They would be in some ratio,but pretty small in comparison to d that one can consider them to be near zero as their squares would make.

Comment: @mechanics The onus is still to show that the conditions can indeed be satisfied.  How do you know that there is enough degrees of freedom to solve this non-linear system of equations, which may not have a solution? I agree that if a solution exists, then 3 variables must be very small, so that's a necessary condition. But why is it sufficient? If there are no positive solutions for a large enough $d$, then you can't draw any conclusions. (It doesn't mean that the expression is bounded, because there could be solutions with a large enough $a$, which is my solution set.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ a+b+c+d = A \geq 26$. (Do you know why we have this constraint?)

We have $ a+b, c+d$ are the roots of $x(A-x) = 143$, or that $ -x^2 + Ax - 143 = 0 $, so they are (with simplification) $ \frac{ A \pm \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 }} { 2}$.
We have $a+c, b+d$ are the roots of $-x^2 + Ax - 150 = 0 $, so they are $\frac{  A\pm \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 }} { 2} $.
We have $ a+d, b+c$ are the roots of $-x^2 + Ax - 169 = 0 $, so they are $ \frac{A \pm \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 2} $.

We (wisely) choose $  a+b =  \frac{ A + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 }} { 2}, a + c = \frac{ A + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 }} { 2}, a + d = \frac{ A + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 }} { 2}$.

These, along with $a+b+c+d = A$ gives the unique solutions:
$$ a = \frac{A+\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\   
b = \frac{A+\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\    
c = \frac{A-\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\    
d  = \frac{A-\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4}.$$

It remains to check that the terms are positive. Clearly $d$ is the smallest, and [Wolfram says it's positive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A-%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+143+%7D+-+%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+150+%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+169+%7D+%3E+0). (Sorry for the cop-out, my original approach didn't work, and I'm too tired to think. Sort-of approach shown below.).

Hence, there is no upper bound for $A$, and neither for $A^2 - 462$.

---

Notes

- I did the selection because of how symmetric those solutions were.
- $A = 26$ gives the minimum value, which we've shown can be achieved.
- If desired, it's easy to verify that these solutions satisfy the equations. IE $ a  + b = \frac{ A + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } } { 2 } $ and $ c+d = \frac{ A - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143} } { 2 } $ (which was how we derived them), so their product is $143$.
- If we didn't choose wisely and instead had $ a+d = \frac{A - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 }} { 2 } $ (and the other equations), then we have the solutions

$$ a' = \frac{A+\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\   
b' = \frac{A+\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\    
c' = \frac{A-\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4},\\    
d'  = \frac{A-\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 } } { 4}.$$

Clearly $d'$ will be negative for some large enough $A$.

- Attempt at proving the inequality$ d > 0$
  WTS $A-\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } > \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 }$
  $\frac{143}{19} > \frac{ A+\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } }{\sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 150 } + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 169 }} $.
  Using the approximation $ \sqrt{ A^2 - k } \approx A - \frac{k}{2A}$, the RHS is approximately $\frac{2A - \frac{2\times 143}{A} }{ 2A - \frac{2 \times 319 } { A } } = \frac{2A^2 - 286}{2A^2 - 638} $. This is decreasing in $A$, so the RHS is $\leq 1.5 $ for $ A \geq 26$, so we have a lot of wriggle room.

Comment: Nice solution. Your solution is simpler than mine.

Comment: @RiverLi It follows from the algebra. IE Clearly $ a  + b = \frac{ A + \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143 } } { 2 } $ and $ c+d = \frac{ A - \sqrt{ A^2 - 4 \times 143} } { 2 } $ (which was how we derived them), so their product is $143$.

Comment: Letting $a + b + c + d = A$ is indeed the key to the problem!

Comment: Another question: How to add a condition such that the maximum exists but the question is still interesting.

Comment: @RiverLi I'm not certain that such a condition exists. I believe that the solution set for $ d(A) > 0$ is the open interval $  (x, \infty)$, where we're allowed to use any 3 constants. The interesting thing is that with a small enough $(a+b)(c+d)$  ( EG [90](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A-%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+90+%7D+-+%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+150+%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B+A%5E2+-+4+%5Ctimes+169+%7D+%3E0) ), the minimum is no longer 26.

Comment: That feels like an arbitrary condition. I was looking at the setup for the question, hence just playing around with the 3 products.   $\quad$ Care to help with my gap of $ d > 0$?

Comment: We should choose the additional condition such that the maximum exists and admits a closed form (or simple form) solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin Using your approach, I found that if at least two of $a, b, c, d$ are bounded from below, then $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ admits a maximum. For example, $a, b \ge 1$, $c, d \ge 0$ and $(a+b)(c+d) = 143, (a+c)(b+d) = 150, (a+d)(b+c) = 169$, then the maximum of $a+ b+ c+ d$ is $\approx 89.97570273$ (the exact value is a root of degree-5 equation).

Answer (score 2):

As @CalvinLin pointed out,
under the conditions, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ is not bounded from above.

*Explanation*:

Let $t\in (0, 1)$ and
$$a = \frac{t}{2} + \frac{Q}{4t},
\quad b = -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{Q}{4t},
\quad c = \frac{143t}{Q} + \frac{19}{2t},
\quad d = \frac{143t}{Q} - \frac{19}{2t}$$
where $Q = \sqrt{ {t}^{4}+638\,{t}^{2}+361} - \sqrt{{t}^{4}+66\,{t}^{2}+361}$.

It is not difficult to verify
that
$a, b, c, d > 0$, and
$(a + b)(c + d) = 143$, and $(a + c)(b + d) = 150$,
and $(a + d)(b + c) = 169$.

However, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = t^2 + 176 + \frac{361}{t^2} \to \infty$ as $t \to 0^{+}$.

---

**Remarks**: Explain how to obtain the above $a, b, c, d$.

Consider the system of equations
\begin{align*}
 (a + b)(c + d) = 143, \tag{1}\\
 (a + c)(b + d) = 150, \tag{2}\\
 (a + d)(b + c) = 169. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
(1) gives
$d = \frac{143}{a + b} - c$.
[(2) - (3)] gives
$(b-a)c + ad - db + 19 = 0$
which results in $c = \frac{81a - 62b}{a^2 - b^2}$.
We see that if $a > b$ and $a-b \to 0^{+}$, then $c \to \infty$. So, we let $a - b = t$.
Then we have
$$4\,{t}^{2}{b}^{4}+8\,{t}^{3}{b}^{3}+ \left( 5\,{t}^{4}-352\,{t}^{2}-
361 \right) {b}^{2}+ \left( {t}^{5}-352\,{t}^{3}-361\,t \right) b-88\,
{t}^{4}+5022\,{t}^{2}
 = 0.$$
We can solve $b$ in closed form. Indeed, dividing both sides by $4t^2$,
we have
$${b}^{4}+2\,t{b}^{3}+ \left( -88+ \frac{5}{4}t^2 -{\frac {361}{4t^2}} \right) {b}^{2}+ \left( -{\frac {361}{4t}} + \frac14{t}^{3}-88
\,t \right) b+{\frac {2511}{2}}-22\,{t}^{2} = 0.
$$
We eliminate the term $b^3$ by letting $b = z - t/2$:
$${z}^{4}+ \left( -{\frac {361}{4t^2}}-88-\frac14{t}^{2} \right) {z
}^{2}+{\frac {20449}{16}} = 0.$$
Luckily, it can be solved in closed form.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added some explanation.

Comment: @CalvinLin It is easy. I will add something.

Comment: Ah thanks! (It's more algebra than I want to wade through, so I'd trust you got it right).

Comment: @CalvinLin Your solution is much simpler than mine.

Comment: $\sqrt{Q} = \sqrt{ (t^4 + 638t^2 + 361 } - \sqrt{ t^4 + 66 t^2 + 361 } $ right?

Comment: @CalvinLin Nice. I did not notice that.

Comment: @CalvinLin This simplifies the result. Thanks.